# Unable to read symbols error

Tags: iphone, xcode

I get these errors when I build and run for the device. Should I be worried about them? The app runs fine.

```
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 10755]
[Switching to thread 10755]
warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "libobjc.A.dylib" for breakpoint 1.

(gdb) continue
warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/tim/Code/Cat War/build/Debug-iphoneos"/Tiger War.app/Tiger War" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/tim/Code/Cat War/build/Debug-iphoneos"/Tiger War.app/Tiger War" (file not found).
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably turned off debug symbols in the build settings.  They *should* be off for release but they are helpful for debuging.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I get this as well, but only when testing on the iPhone or iPod touch. Also, for my Debug Target Config settings, "Generate Debug Symbols" *is* set. (Not much in the Xcode project was changed in terms of the build settings, and I suspect it wasn't in yours either ... ?)

By any chance do you have an objc_exception_throw breakpoint in play? I have these two in my global breakpoints group:

```
[NSException raise] (CoreFoundation)
objc_exception_throw (libobjc.A.dylib)
```

Perhaps there's a correlation?